Integral - Summation equivalence
I was reading an article where I came a cross the following equation:
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \int_{T} x_i(t)\beta(t)dt + \epsilon_i$$
I am trying to understand why there is an integral in this equation?
My guess is that this integral is likely referring to the summation-integral equivalence in limits, e.g.:
$$Y_i \approx \beta_0 + [x_i(0)\beta(0)\Delta t + x_i(0.01)\beta(0.01)\Delta t + x_i(0.02)\beta(0.02)\Delta t + x_i(0.03)\beta(0.03)\Delta t + \ldots] + \epsilon_i$$
Here, $\Delta t$  is small value, e.g.  $\Delta t= 0.01$.
More compactly, suppose we had data from t=0 to t=24:
$$Y_i \approx \beta_0 + \sum_{j=0}^{2399} x_i(0.01j)\beta(0.01j)(0.01) + \epsilon_i$$
Thus in limit, we could write:
$$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum_{j=0}^{24/\Delta t - 1} x_i(j\Delta t)\beta(j\Delta t)\Delta t = \int_0^{24} x_i(t)\beta(t)dt$$
Is my conclusion correct?

Original article: https://www.annualreviews.org/docserver/fulltext/statistics/3/1/annurev-statistics-041715-033624.pdf?expires=1726074837&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=FF5DC6176D505B061BFE97CA41055F0D


I have added some more context!

It is better to include your artcile or otherwise we may not give the correct idea that match with your article. Here I write based on my thoughts.
Usually, $\epsilon_i$ represents some errors between the model we proposed and the actual data (such as in regression analysis). Therefore, there should be a proposed estimator/model with$$Y_i=\beta_0+\int_Tx_i(t)\beta(t)dt$$
Note that we can rewrite the above equation in $$Y_i(t)=\beta_0+\int_0^tx_i(s)\beta(s)~ds$$
This is equivalent to an initial value problem
$$\dfrac{dY_i(t)}{dt}=x_i(t)\beta(t),\quad Y_i(0)=\beta_0$$
Basically this how your is the "first-step" of your model proposed, and the above idea is actually trying to find a closed form of $Y_i(t)$.

thank you so much! I have included a link to the original article: https://www.annualreviews.org/docserver/fulltext/statistics/3/1/annurev-statistics-041715-033624.pdf?expires=1726074837&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=FF5DC6176D505B061BFE97CA41055F0D

Given this information in the original article, is my interpretation correct? thank you

I cannot say you wrong, because that’s the definition of the Riemann integral. But I guess the author proposed the model because they get the ODE or some PDE relation, and they prefer quoting it in an integral closed form, that’s the idea. You can interpret the integral as the discrete sum of those, but I prefer regard it as some accumulated changes.
